# How to do a replace with Kohana_Cache

Tags: php, memcached, kohana-3, kohana-cache

When working with Memcache in PHP, I rely on being able to replace existing values like so:

```
$cache = new Memcache;
$cache->set('foo', 'bar');

$cache->replace('foo', 'baz');
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like Kohana_Cache in Kohana 3.1 supports a replace() method. What the recommended procedure in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend Kohana_Cache_Memcache and do either one of these:

1. add a check to the `Cache_Memcache::set()` method to do a check before calling `Memcache::set()` / `Memcache::replace()`
2. add a `Cache_Memcache::replace()` method

Just be careful when changing the driver later since default Kohana cache drivers are trying to be consistent (so that changing the driver to APC without replicating the behaviour to it doesn't ... you know :).

Comment: I've looked at the code for the actual drivers since I posted originally. What I'm concerned about now is whether set() should do the replace or if an explicit replace() method should be added. Thoughts?

Comment: @Noah Goodrich: I submitted a ticked for this to be fixed, using the code I posted should work fine until then: http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4110 . Altough I'm not sure if replace isn't ambiguous by now, since most sources state that Memcache::set() will update existing data as supposed to.